# How to replace all lines based on previous lines in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, xml, replace, notepad++

I have an XML code:

```
<Line1>Matched_text Other_text</Line1>
<Line2>Text_to_replace</Line2>
```

How to tell Notepad++ to find `Matched_text` and replace `Text_to_replace` to `Replaced_text`? There are several similar blocks of code, with one exactly `Matched _text` and different `Other_text` and `Text_to_replace`. I want to replace all in once.

My idea is to put

```
Matched_text*<Line2>*</Line2>
```

in the Find field, and

```
Matched_text*<Line2>Replaced_text</Line2>
```

in the Replace field. I know that `\1` in regex might be useful, but I don't know where to start.

---

The actual code is:

```
<Name>Matched_text, Other_text</Name>
<IsBillable>false</IsBillable>
<Color>-Text_to_replace</Color>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is something like the following.

Find: `(Matched_text[\w,\s<>\/]*<Color>-).*(</Color>)`

Replace: `\1Replaced_text\2`

Broken down:

```
`()` is how you tell regex that you want to keep things (for use in /1, /2, etc.), these are called capture groups in regex land.

`Matched_text[\w,\s<>\/]*` means you want your anchor `Matched_text` and everything after it up till the next part of the expression.

`<Color>-).*(</Color>)` Select everything between <Color>- and </Color> for replacement.
```

If you have any questions about the expression, I highly recommend looking at a [regex cheatsheet](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/).

[image: Make your NPP Find/Replace look like this]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the `Text_to_replace` are different in each block. Is there a way to replace all at once?

Comment: Updated my answer, but I can only be so accurate without an actual example of what you're working with. So hopefully the updated lines above work for you.

Comment: I have updated the actual code in my question as well. I also have tried testing the example solution with the example code, but it can't find it. I use the latest version of Notepad++